# How to update single column with multiple entries in MySQL in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have 4 columns in a table which are as

`id` = Auto Increment Value 
`user_id` = user id from session 
`short_name` = short name for page 
`status` = status of page

```
Following is the array in the $_POST
Array
(
    [pg_about] => 1
    [pg_tools] => 1
    [pg_in] => 1
    [pg_ex] => 1
    [pg_cats] => 1
    [pg_payee] => 1
    [pg_payment] => 1
    [pg_find] => 1
    [pg_menu] => 1
    [pg_sm] => 1
    [pg_cs] => 1
    [pg_csv] => 1
    [pg_calc] => 1
    [pg_budget] => 1
    [pg_tip] => 1
    [pg_exp_pr] => 1
    [pg_bal] => 1
    [pg_mn_ct_in] => 1
    [pg_mn_ct_ex] => 1
    [pg_mn_sct_in] => 1
    [pg_mn_sct_ex] => 1
    [pg_yr_in] => 1
    [pg_yr_ex] => 1
    [pg_dr_in] => 1
    [pg_dr_ex] => 1
    [pg_ct_in] => 1
    [pg_ct_ex] => 1
    [pg_sct_in] => 1
    [pg_sct_ex] => 1
    [pg_all] => 1
    [pg_all_time] => 1
    [pg_inc_vs_exp] => 1
    [pg_audit] => 1
    [pg_imp] => 1
)
```

`pg_*` are stored in the `short_name` column and the values in the `status`.

Currently I'm using the following method;

```
UPDATE tbl_menu2
   SET status = 0
 WHERE user_id = 5 
   AND short_name = 'pg_in';

UPDATE tbl_menu2
   SET status = '0' 
 WHERE user_id = 5 
   AND short_name = 'pg_ex';
```

...and so on

How can I make it more efficient using single SQL statement.

**Note ; `user_id` will be same for all the 30+ entries.**

**Update ;** I forgot to mention that the `status` will be different it won't be the same `status` value is ***user dependent***.

Comment: somethine like ``AND `short_name` IN (" . implode(',', array_keys($_POST)) . ")``, but **this is vulnerable to SQL injections**

Answer (score 0):

if you have a set of value for short_name you could use a IN clause

```
UPDATE `tbl_menu2` 
SET `status` = '0' 
WHERE  `user_id` = 5 
AND `short_name` IN ( 'pg_in','pg_ex');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same query as following by using `in`

```
UPDATE `tbl_menu2` SET `status` = '0' WHERE  `user_id` = 5 AND `short_name` in( 'pg_in','pg_ex','pg_cats',......);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is MYSQL question but you can use PHP loop.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_menu2 SET status = $value WHERE user_id = 5  AND short_name = '$key'");
 }
```